# How to check if a value exists in the first member of a two dimensional array

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to check if any of the first value of a two-dimensional array has the value i'm testing. The array is like this

```
[[2,5],[3,1],[4,1]]
```

I want to check only the first member of the array (here 2 or 3 or 4)

I'm doing something like this for one dimensional array but it's not working for two

```
[:cart] << [id, 1] unless [:cart].include?(id)
```

Comment: You can use `transpose`.  `001 > array = [[2,5],[3,1],[4,1]]` `002 > array.transpose.first` `=> [2, 3, 4] `

Comment: Do you mean that, given an array `arr`, whose elements are arrays of size 2, and a value `x`, do you wish to determine if the first element of any element of `arr` equals `x`? (Be precise!) If so, simplest may be best: `arr = [[1, 6], [2, 7], [3, 8]]; arr.find { |f,_| f == 2 } #=> [2, 7]`, which produces a *truthy* (as in this example) or *falsy* value. Note that in Ruby one does not generally speak of "n-dimensional arrays".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`any?`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/any%3F) Enumerable function to achieve this as following

```
[:cart] << [id, 1] unless [:cart].any? {|arr| arr[0] == id}
```

Answer (score 4):

When your data requires that the first value of the nested arrays is unique, then a nested array might not be the right data structure for you.

I would suggest a [`Hash`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/Hash.html) instead:

```
cart = { 2 => 5, 3 => 1, 4 => 1 }
cart[id] = 1 unless cart.key?(id)
```

The biggest benefit of using a hash over a nested array in this case would be that the check if a specific key is already in the hash is more performant (`O(1)`) instead of iterating over the array (which would be `O(n)`).

When the values are always numbers and never values like `false` or `nil` then the code can be simplified even more to (as mechanicov pointed out in the comments):

```
cart = { 2 => 5, 3 => 1, 4 => 1 }
cart[id] ||= 1
```

`cart[id] ||= 1` assigns `1` to the key defined by the variable `id` only if `cart[id]` doesn't already return a true-ish value.

Comment: Or even `cart[id] ||= 1` to simplify. Note: to convert existing nested array from the question text `hsh = ary.to_h`

Comment: @mechnicov Great idea! I updated my answer to address your comment.

Comment: I guess I'm late in noticing, but congrats on breaking 10^6.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thank you, you are actually the first noticing...

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`assoc`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.2/Array.html#method-i-assoc) to find a sub-array based on its first value:

```
array = [[2, 5], [3, 1], [4, 1]]

array.assoc(3) #=> [3, 1]
```

Likewise, it can be utilized in a conditional:

```
array << [id, 1] unless array.assoc(id)
```

Note that `assoc` has to traverse the array in order to find the sub-array. If your collection is large, a hash might be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the first numbers into an one-dimensional array and use your currently logic.

```
first_items = arrays.map { |sub_array| sub_array[0] }
```

Answer (score 0):

What's about [pattern matching](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/syntax/pattern_matching_rdoc.html)?

```rb
def add_to_cart_if_absent(cart, id)
  case cart
  in [*, [^id, _], *]
    cart # return same value if match
  else
    cart + [[id, 1]] # return new array with added element
  end
end
```

`*` is splat operator for find pattern

`^` is pin operator to use existing variable in the pattern

`_` is used because we don't care about second element

When `id` exists:

```rb
cart = [[2, 5], [3, 1], [4, 1]]
id = 3

add_to_cart_if_absent(cart, id)
# => [[2, 5], [3, 1], [4, 1]]
```

When `id` is absent:

```rb
cart = [[2, 5], [3, 1], [4, 1]]
id = 33

add_to_cart_if_absent(cart, id)
# => [[2, 5], [3, 1], [4, 1], [33, 1]]
```